# Link fmt library on github-action

Tags: c++, cmake, github-actions, conan

Good day,

I have the following python `conanfile.py`:

```py
from conans import ConanFile


class GeneticAlgorithmProject(ConanFile):
    # Note: options are copied from CMake boolean options.
    # When turned off, CMake sometimes passes them as empty strings.
    # "some_option_name": ["ON", "OFF", ""]
    options = {
    }
    name = "GeneticAlgorithmProject"
    version = "0.1"
    requires = (
        "fmt/8.0.1",
        "effolkronium-random/1.4.0",
        "range-v3/0.11.0"
    )
    generators = "cmake", "gcc", "txt", "cmake_find_package"

    def requirements(self):
        pass
```

And classical runner on `CmakeLists.txt` calling [`Conan.cmake`](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/cpp_starter_project/blob/main/cmake/Conan.cmake) file macro `run_conan()`.

Cmake configure and build `fmt` lib at step `- name: Configure CMake`:

```
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findrange-v3.cmake
-- Found range-v3: 0.11.0 (found version "0.11.0") 
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findeffolkronium_random.cmake
-- Found effolkronium_random: 1.4.0 (found version "1.4.0") 
-- Conan: Using autogenerated Findfmt.cmake
-- Found fmt: 8.0.1 (found version "8.0.1") 
-- Library fmt found /home/runner/work/github_actions/github_actions/conan-cache/.conan/data/fmt/8.0.1/_/_/package/2c09c8f84c016041549fcee94e4caae5d89424b6/lib/libfmt.a
-- Found: /home/runner/work/github_actions/github_actions/conan-cache/.conan/data/fmt/8.0.1/_/_/package/2c09c8f84c016041549fcee94e4caae5d89424b6/lib/libfmt.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/runner/work/github_actions/github_actions/build
```

But in the next step `- name: Build` github couldn't find `-lfmt`

```
Run CC=gcc-11 CXX=g++-11 cmake --build ./build --config Release
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/genetic_algo.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable genetic_algo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfmt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/genetic_algo.dir/build.make:97: genetic_algo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/genetic_algo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Here is yml file:

```yaml
name: Test Cmake and Conan

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
  # Conan cache environment variables
  CONAN_SYSREQUIRES_MODE: enabled
  CONAN_USER_HOME: "${{ github.workspace }}/conan-cache"
  CONAN_USER_HOME_SHORT: "${{ github.workspace }}/conan-cache/short"

# Use a bash shell so we can use the same syntax for environment variable
# access regardless of the host operating system
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:
  build:

    name: ${{ matrix.config.name }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {
            name: "Linux GCC 11 Release (C++20, Concepts)", artifact: "Linux.tar.xz",
            os: ubuntu-latest,
            cc: "gcc-11", cxx: "g++-11",
            cxx_standard: 20
          }

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        env:
          cache-name: cache-conan-modules
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ env.CONAN_USER_HOME }}
            ~/.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}-${{ hashFiles('CMakeLists.txt') }}-${{ hashFiles('cmake/Conan.cmake') }}

      - name: Create Build Environment
        run: cmake -E make_directory ./build

      - name: Install gcc
        if: startsWith(matrix.config.os,'ubuntu')
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ${{ env.HOME }}
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y ${{matrix.config.cc}} ${{matrix.config.cxx}}

      - name: Install conan
        run: |
          pip3 install wheel setuptools
          pip3 install conan --upgrade

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: |
          CC=${{matrix.config.cc}} CXX=${{matrix.config.cxx}} cmake -S . -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}

      - name: Build
        run: |
          CC=${{matrix.config.cc}} CXX=${{matrix.config.cxx}} cmake --build ./build --config ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}

      - name: Test
        working-directory: ./build
        # Execute tests defined by the CMake configuration.
        # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html for more detail
        run: |
          CC=${{matrix.config.cc}} CXX=${{matrix.config.cxx}} ctest -C ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}
```

Of course on local machine everything were build.

Comment: Sometimes, a small discrepancy in the binary format makes the linker ignore the library altogether. Like if the library is with the wrong architecture or something. Maybe it is possible that the environment or compiler used in the Github action has something different. Does the output contain the profile used? Also, what linkage are you using in your consumer CMakeLists.txt? ``CONAN_LIBS``, ``CONAN_PKG::fmt``?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to link `fmt` library is

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

I use simple `fmt` without prefix but github wouldn't like this way.